# Call class from external file in parallel pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, pyspark, rdd, distributed-computing

I'm trying to distribute data with IDs in cluster then call another class to do complex logic on these IDs in parallel in pySpark. I'm so confused of how to sort things out as the code below did not work

I have file myprocess.py contains

```
def class MyProcess():
   def __init__(self, sqlcontext, x):
      /* code here */
   def complex_calculation(self):
      /* lots of sql and statiscal steps */
```

Then I have my main wrapper control.py
warehouse_location = abspath('spark-warehouse')

```
spark = SparkSession \
     .builder \
     .appName("complexlogic") \
     .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouse_location) \
     .enableHiveSupport() \
     .getOrCreate()


sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")


sc.addPyFile(r"myprocess.py")

from myprocess import MyProcess


sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
settings_bc = sc.broadcast({
    'mysqlContext': sqlContext
})

/**
some code to create df_param
**/
df = df_param.repartition("id")
print('number of partitions', df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
rdd__param = df.rdd.map(lambda x: MyProcess(settings_bc.value, x).complex_calculation()).collect()
```

The error I get

```
_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize broadcast: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

I understand that error is probably regarding passing sqlContext, but I think my issue is larger than that error, it is what is the right way to do what I'm trying to achieve (**Edit**: I'm trying to use the ID to filter 17 hive tables with that id and use these 17 tables to do complex math. If I move outside map how I will achieve parallelism) . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the error message carefully? You cannot use sparkContext instance in worker nodes which you might be using inside MyProcess class.

Comment: Hi @Ramesh, I got that, do you have any suggestion what is the solution?

Comment: try to move the codes that use sparkContext in the driver class itself i.e. outside the map function

Comment: The point here is to use the ID to filter 17 hive tables with that id and use these 17 tables to do complex math. If I move outside map how I will achieve parallelism?